# Can the F# compiler use currying to separate code paths based on type?

Tags: f#, compiler-optimization, currying, discriminated-union, branch-prediction

Can the F# compiler separate out code paths by currying a function in which different types imply different paths through subsequent called functions?

Consider the following discriminated union. There are 2 possibilities, which are theoretically different types:

```
type Choice =
    | Halve
    | Double
```

Suppose we have some specific functions for some of these cases:

```
let halve value = value / 2.0
let divide value = value * 2.0
```

And 2 functions which provide 2 separate code paths depending on the type of some `param` (remainder to complete the fs file):

```
let inner param value = 
    match param with
    | Choice.Halve -> halve value
    | Choice.Double -> divide value

let outer param value =
    let internalVariable = 
        match param with
        | Choice.Halve -> "halving"
        | Choice.Double -> "doubling"
    inner param value


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printf "%g\n" (outer Choice.Halve 4.0)
    let doubler = outer Choice.Double
    printf "%g\n" (doubler 6.0)
```

The Halve and Double are thus separate code paths, and we could have written them as two separate functions.

Theoretically, currying would say that there are two different functions; if you curry the first parameter to either of the Choice.Halve or Choice.Double types (like in `doubler`), then you have a function specific to that type and the compiler should be able to optimise later branches out.

Is that the case?

If I look in the IL, I can see no such optimisation but I suppose it's possible that this is JITted. A colleague suggests that branch prediction makes such optimisations unnecessary.

Is the only way to avoid the unnecessary branches to invert the structure and pass the `divide`/`halve` function in?

-- Edit --

John Palmer suggested adding `inline`, so I tried it and got the following optimised IL for `outer`:

```
IL_0001: ldarg.0
IL_0002: call instance int32 Program/Choice::get_Tag()
IL_0007: ldc.i4.1
IL_0008: bne.un.s IL_0016

IL_000a: ldarg.1
IL_000b: ldc.r8 2
IL_0014: mul
IL_0015: ret

IL_0016: ldarg.1
IL_0017: ldc.r8 2
IL_0020: div
IL_0021: ret
```

However, there is no apparent optimisation of the `doubler` curried function in `main` - so the uncurried function is being optimised, but not the curried one.

Comment: Have you tried using `inline` on any of the functions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the compiler will do this automatically, but you can write your code so that it implements this explicitly:

```
let inner param = 
    match param with
    | Choice.Halve -> (fun value -> halve value)
    | Choice.Double -> (fun value -> divide value)
```

This function can be used in the same way as your original function, e.g. `inner 1.0 2.0`, but when you call it with just a single argument, it actually runs the first part of the body and returns a function created in the body of the match case.

Comment: And note that `(fun value -> halve value)` is just an eta-expanded way of writing `halve`.

Comment: So if I replaced `halve value` with `halve`, `divide value` with `divide` and removed value from the argument list of `inner`, that would provide a separate path and get optimised? Why is there such a difference?